# apply css to a html element after finding some specific class name avaialble

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to apply css to a div(.references) after finding a specific class name(.overview) available in anywhere in that document. its not working
.references div not inside .overview div

```
if ($('div').hasClass('overview')) {

    $('.references').css("display", "none !important");   
}
```

Please help

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).find('div').each(function (){if($(this).hasClass('overview'){  $('.references').css("display", "none !important");   })})`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('div').hasClass('overview'() {

    $('.references').css("display", "none !important");
})
```

Try That

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".overview").length > 0)
    {
         $('.references').css("display", "none !important");
    }
});
```

Here we are just checking whether there is any element in DOM with class `.overview` present or not. If its present then `$(".overview").length` will return you number of element(s) which present and which we are comparing with `0`. So if its there then we are applying required CSS to `$('.references')` element.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `!important`. Just use `$('.references').css("display", "none");`

Other options

```
$('.references').css("cssText", "display: none !important");
```

Or

```
$('.references').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

> here u can see in my snippet, i used hide() to hide .references class, This will help u

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if ($('div').hasClass('overview')) {

    $('.references').hide();   
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>sample sample sample sample sample samplevsample sample sample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample sample
    </div>
  
  <div class="overview references">sample sample sample sample sample samplevsample sample sample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample samplesample sample
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  if($('div.overview').length > 0){
     $('.references').hide();
  }
});
```

`$(function() {...});` is a Shorthand for $( document ).ready().